# Como manter a restrição de chave estrangeira usando softdelete?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Como eu posso manter a integridade do meu banco de dados quando estou usando `softdelete`?

**Exemplo:** tento excluir uma **pessoa** que está ligada a uma **conta** através de uma **chave estrangeira**, em vias normais isso não será possível pois viola a restrição de **chave estrangeira**, mas usando o `softdelete` é possível até porque `softdelete` é um `update`.

Alguém tem uma dica de como manter a restrição de chave estrangeira usando `softdelete`?

***Observação:*** estou usando o método

```
delete();
```

Comment: @geek.com fico alguma duvida, não era isso que você queria?

Comment: opa @VirgilioNovic, muito boa sua resposta realmente ajudou muito, mas eu resolvi de uma forma diferente, vou propor como resposta e esperar a votação da comunidade sobre qual solução seria mais interessante.

Comment: ok @geek.com, eu também estou ansioso em ver essa outra abordagem, fico no aguardo.

Answer (score 4):

Você tem muita razão no que diz, mas, essa é um das formas propostas pelo [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) para não excluir sumariamente o dado (*permanentemente*), ficando até como histórico em sua ***base***, tendo a possibilidade de pesquisas de dados antigos, que é muito importante no meu entender.

Acredito que a demonstração de um exemplo minimo de uma relação seria o ideal para o seu entendimento:

***Modelos***

#### Pessoa:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Pessoa extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = array('nome');
    protected $table = "pessoas";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function contas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Conta::class, 'pessoa_id','id');
    }
}
```

#### Conta

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Conta extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = array('conta', 'pessoa_id');
    protected $table = "contas";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function pessoa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pessoa::class,'pessoa_id','id');
    }
}
```

Se for executado um comando `delete()` no *model* `Pessoa`, como exemplo abaixo:

```
Pessoa::find(1)->delete();
```

como está usando o recurso [SoftDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting), é atualizado o campo `deleted_at` com uma data atual e com isso esse registro é considerado `deletado`. O que pude entender é que deseja simular o que o banco faria, dando um `erro` por existir dados na relação com o **model** `Conta`, ou seja, existe na tabela de ***contas*** dados com a relação de ***pessoa*** do `id` igual *1*. Um erro parecido como esse:

> 17:42:03  delete from pessoas where id = 1 Error Code: 1451. Cannot
>   delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db1`.`contas`, CONSTRAINT `contas_pessoa_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`pessoa_id`) REFERENCES `pessoas` (`id`)

**Como poderia então, proteger esse registro usando** [**SoftDeletes**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting)?

A unica maneira é fazer pesquisas nas relações existente com `pessoas`, no caso exemplo `contas`:

```
if (Conta::where('pessoa_id', 1)->count() == 0)
{
    Pessoa::find(1)->delete();
}
```

essa é a maneira que tem, ou seja, *via* ***programação***, mas, tem talvez um problema, se a tabela `pessoas` tiver varias relações tem que conferir todas as relações, para então, dar o comando `delete()`. Vale lembrar que em `contas` pode estar usando também o recurso de [SoftDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting), e se por acaso for excluído todas as contas, automáticamente, pode excluir a `pessoa` com esse simples código. Se assim preferir pode dar um mensagem que essa *pessoa* não pode ser excluída, por ter relações (pendencias):

```
if (Conta::where('pessoa_id', 1)->count() == 0)
{
    Pessoa::find(1)->delete();
} 
else
{
    //texto meramente ilustrativo, pode ser tomada outras decisões
    echo "Não pode ser excluido por ter relação com contas";
}
```

**Observação:** se todos os seus modelos (`Model`) estiverem usando o recurso de [SoftDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting), é o ideal usar o comando `delete` nas relações (não existe nada implementado que resolva de uma maneira só, pelo menos até agora), e só lembrando que com esse recurso a sua base ficaria com o ***histórico das informações*** e com comandos extras, pode esses dados serem recuperados.

***Exemplo de como recuperar um registro excluído com [SoftDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting)***

**Recuperando o registro excluído**:

```
$pessoa = Pessoa::withTrashed()
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->first();
```

**Restaurando o item excluído**:

```
$pessoa->restore();
```

E por fim, existem também uma [forma de força a exclusão sumária](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) (excluir realmente o registro do banco) com o seguinte método:

**Excluir definitivamente o registro da tabela**:

```
$pessoa->forceDelete();
```

<sub>**Observação:** se houver relação entre as tabelas e registros que faça a relação, no momento da exclusão o banco não permitira e enviará um erro [foreign key constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting)
- [Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models)
- [Querying Soft Deleted Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models)
- [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Vou resumir a solução que eu adotei em alguns passos:

**1.** Tentando forçar o delete físico (definitivo), como existe restrição de chave estrangeira no banco de dados o método executa um **rollback** na transação.

```
$pessoa->forceDelete();
DB::rollback();
```

**2.** Executa um delete lógico (softdelete).

```
$pessoa = Pessoa::findOrFail($id);
$pessoa->delete();
```

**3.** Confirma a transação.

```
DB::commit()
```

**4.** Recuperando as exceções: QueryException(PDOException),

```
catch (QueryException $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    $pessoa = array('mensagem' => 'impossível excluir esse dado');
```

Abaixo o código completo, espero que fique claro.

```
    use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

    private function destroy($id)
    {

    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        $pessoa = Pessoa::findOrFail($id);

        //1
        $pessoa->forceDelete();
        DB::rollback();

        //2
        $pessoa = Pessoa::findOrFail($id);
        $pessoa->delete();

        //3
        DB::commit();

        //4
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        $pessoa = array('mensagem' => 'impossível excluir esse dado');
    }

        return $pessoa;
    }
```

**Referência:** [Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions)

Comment: porque causar exceção? porque, não verificar, então se existe registros que pode ou não ser excluído definitivamente, e também agora surgiu a duvida, se quer excluir se não tiver relação e se tiver fica no `softdelete`? Desculpa, dizer mais é bem problemático essa solução visto que existe uma opção de verificar sem dar erros. Bom não me leve a mau, são observações ... ;)

Comment: Tranquilo @VirgilioNovic, vamos lá as minhas ideias pra tentar te passar melhor o que eu pensei:

Comment: 1. Por que causar exceção?
Isso é um "truque", apenas para gerar uma exceção e depois tratá-la.

2. Por que, não verificar, então se existe registros que pode ou não ser excluído definitivamente?
Nesse ponto eu pensei no desempenho: imagine fazer um count() em muitas entidades em busca de relacionamentos, imagino que talvez assim fosse mais veloz, talvez eu esteja errado.

3. Se quer excluir se não tiver relação e se tiver fica no softdelete? 
Exatamente, manterei o softdelete.

Comment: Então, o item 2) pode ser feito de forma otimizada, verificando 1 relacionamento por vezes e se achar itens retornar false e fazer um `softdelete` (dá pra otimizar, principalmente pela precedência das tabelas), e em um entidade não tem muitos relacionamentos se as mesmas estiverem montadas na `3FN` corretamente. o 1 sinceramente não vou comentar, a 3 eu concordo. Bom, tem como fazer melhor sem `try catch` que deveria ser usado quando foge da ação do desenvolvedor, mas, tudo bem @geekcom vlw.

Comment: Bom, é uma alternativa, não direi que é a melhor e nem a única, sobre o que você disse no item 2, eu concordo, vou tirar uns momentos nesse trecho pra tentar algo melhor, assim que desenvolver vou atualizar a resposta.